# vb.net alternative to select case when dealing with object values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, select, case

Hey all, I was able to do this via a SELECT CASE statement, however I'm always trying to improve my code writing and was wondering if there was a better approach.  Here's the scenario:

Each document has x custom fields on it.
There's y number of documents
However there's only 21 distinct custom fields, but they can obviously have n different combinations of them depending on the form.

So here's what I did, I created an object called CustomFields like so:

```
 Private Class CustomFields
    Public agentaddress As String
    Public agentattorney As String
    Public agentcity As String
    Public agentname As String
    Public agentnumber As String
    Public agentstate As String
    Public agentzip As String
    ... more fields here ....
End Class`
```

Then I went ahead and assigned the values I get from the user to each of those fields like so:

```
Set All of Our Custom Fields Accordingly
        Dim pcc As New CustomFields()
        pcc.agentaddress = agent.address1
        pcc.agentattorney = cplinfo.attorneyname
        pcc.agentcity = agent.city
        pcc.agentname = agent.agencyName
        pcc.agentnumber = agent.agentNumber
        pcc.agentstate = agent.state
        pcc.agentzip = agent.zip ....other values set to fields etc.
```

Now the idea is based upon what combo of fields come back based upon the document, we need to assign the value which matches up with that custom field's value.  So if the form only needed agentaddress and agentcity:

```
'Now Let's Loop Through the Custom Fields for This Document
        For Each cf As vCustomField In cc
            Dim customs As New tblCustomValue()

            Select Case cf.fieldname
                Case "agentaddress"
                    customs.customfieldid = cf.customfieldid
                    customs.icsid = cpl.icsID
                    customs.value = pcc.additionalinfo
                Case "agentcity"
                    customs.customfieldid = cf.customfieldid
                    customs.icsid = cpl.icsID
                    customs.value = pcc.additionalinfo
End Select

            _db.tblCustomValues.InsertOnSubmit(customs)
            _db.SubmitChanges()
```

This works, however we may end up having 100's of fields in the future so there a way to somehow "EVAL" (yes I know that doesn't exist in vb.net) the cf.fieldname and find it's corresponding value in the CustomFields object?

Just trying to write more efficient code and looking for some brainstorming here.  Hopefully my code and description makes sense.  If it doesn't let me know and I'll go hit my head up against the wall and try writing it again.

Comment: Your final code snippet looks incomplete, and, with what _is_ present, the content of the two `Case` statements is currently identical.

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading your question correctly, you are trying to avoid setting the value of fields, when the field isn't used.  If so, I would recommend you just go ahead and set the field to nothing in that case.